# XSLT recursive substitution of string parameters

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am quite new to XSLT,
I have a source XML message, which in its simplified version looks something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<Message>
    <Invalid>
        <InvalidBody>
            <SynchError>
                <ErrorText>The value of %1 should not be %2.</ErrorText>
                <ErrorParameter>
                    <!-- Error Parameter is %1 identifier -->
                    <ErrorParameterType>value</ErrorParameterType>
                    <ErrorParameterValue>someField</ErrorParameterValue>
                </ErrorParameter>
                <ErrorParameter>
                    <!-- Error Parameter is %2 identifier -->
                    <ErrorParameterType>value</ErrorParameterType>
                    <ErrorParameterValue>someValue</ErrorParameterValue>
                </ErrorParameter>               
            </SynchError>
        </InvalidBody>
    </Invalid>
</Message>
```

Now, I would like to use XSLT 1.0 to extract the ErrorText string and substitute the parameters %1 and %2 with the corresponding ErrorParameter/ErrorParameterValue values. The number of parameters %1, %2, %3... cannot be known in advance, so the solution should be flexible enough to accommodate a variable number of parameters.

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any control over the format of the input? The way you have it now, it's going to be very difficult to extract the number following the % flag, since the character after that is unknown (in your example you have a space, then a period).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the input. It is feeded by an external Webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after quite a lot of googling around and a healthy dose of headache, I came up with the following solution, which seems to work like a charm:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="err-text" select="/Message/Invalid/InvalidBody/SynchError/ErrorText" />
        <xsl:variable name="param-count" select="count(/Message/Invalid/InvalidBody/SynchError/ErrorParameter)" />

        <xsl:call-template name="replace-params">
                <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$param-count"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="source-text" select="$err-text" />
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="replace-params">
        <xsl:param name="position"/>
        <xsl:param name="source-text"/>     

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$position = 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$source-text"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:call-template name="replace-params">
                            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position - 1"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="source-text">
                                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$source-text" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="concat('%', $position)" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="/Message/Invalid/InvalidBody/SynchError/ErrorParameter[$position]/ErrorParameterValue" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:param name="replace" />
        <xsl:param name="by" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
              select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use the "string-replace-all" template as a substitute for the XSLT 2.0 replace() function, since I cannot exclude multiple occurrences of a single parameter.
The "replace-params" template is applied recursively on the original text, iterating backwards on the index of the set of ErrorParameters.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have tackled similar problems is to create a named template that recurses through the string (text element of) `<ErrorText>` with each cycle picking out the first n% item, then dereferences the `<ErrorParameter>` to access the contents of that and store in a result, then snip off the n% item just process and calls itself to grab the next one.  When there are no more %n items left, return the result.

Here's an example of that, this template basically counts comma-separated items in a parameter passed in on the first cycle called List, and returns a $Count when it's finished.

`<xsl:template name="CountList">
    <xsl:param name="List"/>
    <xsl:param name="Count" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($List,',') = false()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Count"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="CountList">
        <xsl:with-param name="List">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($List,',')"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="Count">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Count + 1"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. You can use a replace instead of 'substring-before' and 'after' if this function is supported.

```
<xsl:template match="SynchError">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ErrorParameter[1]">
    <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="ErrorText"/></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="position">1</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ErrorParameter">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:param name="position"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following::ErrorParameter">
    <xsl:with-param name="position"><xsl:value-of select="number($position)+1"/></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text,concat('%',$position)),ErrorParameterValue,substring-after($text,concat('%',$position)))"/></xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:if test="not(following::ErrorParameter)">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text,concat('%',$position)),ErrorParameterValue,substring-after($text,concat('%',$position)))"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*You can use a replace ... if this function is supported.*" This question is tagged XSLT 1.0 - so there's no if about it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="merge">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="Message/Invalid/InvalidBody/SynchError/ErrorText"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parameters" select="Message/Invalid/InvalidBody/SynchError/ErrorParameter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="merge">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="parameters"/>
    <xsl:param name="flag" select="'%'"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, $flag)">
            <xsl:variable name="subsequent-char" 
                          select="substring(translate(substring-after($string, $flag), '0123456789', ''), 1, 1)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="i" 
                          select="substring-before(substring-after($string, $flag), $subsequent-char)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $flag)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$parameters[number($i)]/ErrorParameterValue"/>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, concat($flag, $i))"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="parameters" select="$parameters"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```